# How to setup Skype Web SDK to accept login from database of Users from personal db

Tags: asp.net, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have an issue. I am a newbie to the Skype Web SDK and O365 development. I am trying to integrate the Skype web sdk with my ASP.NET Core Web app. I have registered and confirmed ASPNETUsers in my Database, I want to setup the Skype Web SDK to enable skype once a user is signed into the app and he/she can talk with another registered user in the ASPNETUser database table. From the tutorials I have seen, it caters to only office 365 work accounts or special domain email addresses. 
Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Skype For Business Online with your locally created users. They have to be accounts that are linked to your organisation's active directory. Normal registered users won't work.